# Removing noindex posts from wp_query

Tags: posts, wp-query, noindex

I have a blog website with some old posts and they appear in my "featured" posts section.
I put those posts with noindex and but they still show up. is there a way to remove them from wp_query?

Comment: Please share us what have you tried so far?

Comment: mostly searched on here and google and found nothing.. dont really know even where to start

Comment: There is `pre_get_posts` hook to customize query. You can exclude certain  posts from the query with using `post__not_in` parameter. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/ if it may help.

Comment: Do you want to remove them from every query? Do you want remove them only from featured post?

Comment: I want to avoid using post__not_in because it's a lot of posts in diffrent categories and i dont want to change the code everytime a post is added to my list.
I want that if a post has noindex it will not show on the posts that come back from the query. I'm not sure about the diffrence between remove from query or from output.